# Compiling a dynamic library on MacOS with library search path that points to the same directory (CMake)

Tags: c++, macos, linker, cmake, rpath

I'm trying to compile a dylib on MacOS using CMake. My library is dynamically linked to some other libraries and I want to ship them with my library. For this I need to make sure that when I load my library, the dependent libraries are loaded from the same folder regardless its location. I believe that it has something to do with rpath, but I'm not an expert here. Can you please suggest a way to achieve this using CMake? (I guess one needs to provide some linker options via -Wl,-rpath or similar

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have done in my CMake scripts for the shared libraries to be loaded from the same directory as my binaries (executables and other libraries):

```
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH true)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/")
```

(tested with CMake 3.0+)

How it works (my understanding): the second line tells CMake to add the $ORIGIN special string to the binaries search folder (This special $ORIGIN string is "replaced" by the OS, at execution time, with the folder containing the executing binary. So, a needed library that is next to the binary containing this string will be correctly found).

However, setting this variable in CMake only impacts the **install-time** binaries (those that are deployed with **make install**, for instance): CMake does not change the search path in binaries created at the build stage, but only when it installs them.

Since I am not using the CMake install feature, and I only want to supply my application in a freely-relocatable folder, I have used the first call, that tells CMake to use the install-time search paths at build time, too.

So, with these two calls, calling **make** (or building with XCode, I guess) on the CMake-generated makefiles will create binaries with the search folder correctly set to $ORIGIN.

Please do this before defining any other target. You can also customize these settings for individual targets by using set_target_property with the     BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH and INSTALL_RPATH properties.

**I have only tested this under Linux**, but if MacOS X behaves in the same way, this should be OK.

Hope this helps

Benjamin

Answer (score 1):

Linux ${ORIGIN} trick will not work. On macOS, libraries dependencies are by default specified as absolute path ( `otool -L mylib.dylib`).

To have relative path (eg. same folder) I think the proper way is to change the installation names of the dependent libraries inside your main library (with `install_name_tool -change ...`) to something like *@rpath/other.dylib* with correct rpath in the executable (dylib) or in your case just *@executable_path/other.dylib*.

Regarding CMake, I have successfully used CMake [BundleUtilities](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/BundleUtilities.html) module to fix this automatically, it might be worth a try.